# Django (DRF) - Filter parent in recursive field based on child properties

Tags: django, recursion, django-rest-framework

I have a model that's recursive.

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    # recursive relationship
    organization = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='organizations')
```

I have another model that is a child of this recursive model and it can be a child at any point in the tree.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length=8, default=increment_registration_no, unique=True)
    organization = models.OneToOneField(Organization, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='store', null=True)
```

In the UI for this application the list of stores is listed in a recursive table with the organization headers above. We have a serializer specifically designed for this list. When the user is looking at this list they can filter by `Organization` and `Store` properties.

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    registration_no = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('id', 'registration_no')

class StoreFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    registration_no = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        # Turn single object into a query so that we can use django filters
        queryset = Store.objects.filter(pk=value.id)
        registration_no = self.context['request'].query_params.get('registration_no', None)

        if registration_no is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(registration_no__icontains=registration_no)

        if queryset:
            # Represent object with serializer defined above
            return StoreSerializer(queryset[0]).data
        else:
            return {}

    class Meta:
        model = Store


class OrganizationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = StoreFilterSerializer(read_only=True)
    organizations = RecursiveField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('id', 'business_name', 'organization', 'organizations', 'store')
```

As you can see above, if we pass in a `registration_no` then the stores can be filtered out. However, let's say the user enters a string that doesn't match a single store. Then no stores will be returned but a bunch of organizations will be returned. In the UI this causes the the table to be empty because there are no store rows but the pagination menu has every single page because the organizations aren't filtered.

**So the question is**, how do I filter the organizations on whether or not they will have a store somewhere down the recursive tree AFTER the store filters (registration_no) have been applied?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up going with was to filter the stores that I needed and to get the organizations rather than to filter the organizations based on store properties.

**Filter the stores**
various ways to do this

**Get all the parents of the stores**

```
all_orgs = []
for store in store_queryset:
  all_orgs.push(store.get_all_parents())
```

**Get all the orgs**
queryset = Organizations.objects.filter(organization__in=all_orgs)
Then return the orgs